# I rendered 30 days but left behind a unbalanced one category

Tags: resignation, work-experience, stress

The branch I was assigned to was understaffed so I do both workloads, for the supervisor position and mine as assistant in operations. I also do accounting entries, reports, checks, investment,fillings, bills, supplies, and lot more but was not allowed over time.

On top of that a supervisor from another department mistreats and nags at me as well as asks me to do chores for her. Being too occupied in those areas I wasn't able to do an adjustment entry for one particular category and when I finally had a supervisor it turned out that she's a newbie and asked me for a lot of demonstrations to perform duties. This consumed a lot of my time since I was doing most of her work.

When I couldn't take it anymore I resigned - I rendered 30 days and finally got off the job. But 1 month after they were audited they found out about the unadjusted category which I mentioned before. Do I still have the responsibility to deal with it?

Comment: Did you report that the adjustment needed doing at the time it should have been done?

Answer (score 15):

Why would you have responsibility for it?

Let's simplify the picture to help make things clearer.  You work for, say, a company that sells hats - and you're their only hat sales staff.  A call comes in: ABC Enterprises didn't get their hats they ordered last month.  You wouldn't expect to get Alice - the former hat saleswoman - to handle this.  Because she no longer works for the company, and the company hired you to take over her responsibilities.  It's now *your* job to handle whatever responsibilities Alice had - it's now *your* responsibility to fix this problem.  That's why they hired you.

Likewise, you leave the hat game (it's a cruel business that chews up and spits out even the very best) - so the company hires/appoints someone to take over your hat-selling responsibilities.  So if another problem crops up, guess what?  The new hat salesperson has to deal with it.

Once you leave a job, you have *zero* responsibilities to that company (assuming you weren't doing something illegal.)  Whoever took over your responsibilities is the person that needs to handle whatever problems have cropped up in their process - *even if those problems were due to a mistake you made during your time there.*  (And that's perfectly fine.  I'm a computer programmer, and I can tell you: *NONE* of us ever leave a job where we didn't screw up at least *one* thing - bugs happen, and a lot of dev time is maintenance.)

Comment: "I'm a computer programmer, and I can tell you: NONE of us ever leave a job where we didn't screw up at least one thing" ... I shiver at the thought of having to be responsible for all possible code bugs introduced over the last 15 years on any of the jobs I've had!! What a terrifying thought

Comment: "maintenance" is just the polite form of "yelling at the things your predecessor left behind"